# save a html webpage as pdf using php

Tags: php

We all know that we can save a webpage as pdf by pressing CTRL+P and then save as pdf. But how it can be done directly using php? Please note that the webpage is pre-designed and I need to save it as pdf

Comment: Have you tried [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) ?

Comment: I don't understand mpdf. I want to capture HTML output. But on manual I saw this:
ob_start();
//This is where your script would normally output the HTML using echo or print
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

Comment: and I dont understand it @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: I asked that. Have you tried the mpdf plugin/extension/library ?

Comment: mpdf is a php library that can create pdf from html. There are other libraries as well, but mpdf is quite known and tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), look at this example that gives [this result](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf);

```
<?php
//============================================================+
// File name   : example_006.php
// Begin       : 2008-03-04
// Last Update : 2013-05-14
//
// Description : Example 006 for TCPDF class
//               WriteHTML and RTL support
//
// Author: Nicola Asuni
//
// (c) Copyright:
//               Nicola Asuni
//               Tecnick.com LTD
//               www.tecnick.com
//               info@tecnick.com
//============================================================+

/**
 * Creates an example PDF TEST document using TCPDF
 * @package com.tecnick.tcpdf
 * @abstract TCPDF - Example: WriteHTML and RTL support
 * @author Nicola Asuni
 * @since 2008-03-04
 */

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 006', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// writeHTML($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='')
// writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html='', $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true)

// create some HTML content
$html = '<h1>HTML Example</h1>
Some special characters: &lt; € &euro; &#8364; &amp; è &egrave; &copy; &gt; \\slash \\\\double-slash \\\\\\triple-slash
<h2>List</h2>
List example:
<ol>
    <li><img src="images/logo_example.png" alt="test alt attribute" width="30" height="30" border="0" /> test image</li>
    <li><b>bold text</b></li>
    <li><i>italic text</i></li>
    <li><u>underlined text</u></li>
    <li><b>b<i>bi<u>biu</u>bi</i>b</b></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.tecnick.com" dir="ltr">link to http://www.tecnick.com</a></li>
    <li>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.<br />Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</li>
    <li>SUBLIST
        <ol>
            <li>row one
                <ul>
                    <li>sublist</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>row two</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><b>T</b>E<i>S</i><u>T</u> <del>line through</del></li>
    <li><font size="+3">font + 3</font></li>
    <li><small>small text</small> normal <small>small text</small> normal <sub>subscript</sub> normal <sup>superscript</sup> normal</li>
</ol>
<dl>
    <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
    <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
<div style="text-align:center">IMAGES<br />
<img src="images/logo_example.png" alt="test alt attribute" width="100" height="100" border="0" /><img src="images/tcpdf_box.svg" alt="test alt attribute" width="100" height="100" border="0" /><img src="images/logo_example.jpg" alt="test alt attribute" width="100" height="100" border="0" />
</div>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


// output some RTL HTML content
$html = '<div style="text-align:center">The words &#8220;<span dir="rtl">&#1502;&#1494;&#1500; [mazel] &#1496;&#1493;&#1489; [tov]</span>&#8221; mean &#8220;Congratulations!&#8221;</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// test some inline CSS
$html = '<p>This is just an example of html code to demonstrate some supported CSS inline styles.
<span style="font-weight: bold;">bold text</span>
<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">line-trough</span>
<span style="text-decoration: underline line-through;">underline and line-trough</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 64);">color</span>
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">background color</span>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span>
<span style="font-size: xx-small;">xx-small</span>
<span style="font-size: x-small;">x-small</span>
<span style="font-size: small;">small</span>
<span style="font-size: medium;">medium</span>
<span style="font-size: large;">large</span>
<span style="font-size: x-large;">x-large</span>
<span style="font-size: xx-large;">xx-large</span>
</p>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// Print a table

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// create some HTML content
$subtable = '<table border="1" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4"><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr><tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr></table>';

$html = '<h2>HTML TABLE:</h2>
<table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th align="right">RIGHT align</th>
        <th align="left">LEFT align</th>
        <th>4A</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td bgcolor="#cccccc" align="center" colspan="2">A1 ex<i>amp</i>le <a href="http://www.tcpdf.org">link</a> column span. One two tree four five six seven eight nine ten.<br />line after br<br /><small>small text</small> normal <sub>subscript</sub> normal <sup>superscript</sup> normal  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla<ol><li>first<ol><li>sublist</li><li>sublist</li></ol></li><li>second</li></ol><small color="#FF0000" bgcolor="#FFFF00">small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small</small></td>
        <td>4B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>'.$subtable.'</td>
        <td bgcolor="#0000FF" color="yellow" align="center">A2 € &euro; &#8364; &amp; è &egrave;<br/>A2 € &euro; &#8364; &amp; è &egrave;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF00" align="left"><font color="#FF0000">Red</font> Yellow BG</td>
        <td>4C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1A</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFCC">2AA<br />2AB<br />2AC</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000">4D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>4E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1C</td>
        <td>2C</td>
        <td>3C</td>
        <td>4F</td>
    </tr>
</table>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// Print some HTML Cells

$html = '<span color="red">red</span> <span color="green">green</span> <span color="blue">blue</span><br /><span color="red">red</span> <span color="green">green</span> <span color="blue">blue</span>';

$pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,0);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 'LRTB', 1, 0, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 'LRTB', 1, 1, true, 'C', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 'LRTB', 1, 0, true, 'R', true);

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// Print a table

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// create some HTML content
$html = '<h1>Image alignments on HTML table</h1>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" /></td></tr>
<tr style="text-align:left;"><td><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" align="top" /></td></tr>
<tr style="text-align:center;"><td><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" align="middle" /></td></tr>
<tr style="text-align:right;"><td><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" align="bottom" /></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left;"><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" align="top" /></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" align="middle" /></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:right;"><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="41" width="41" align="bottom" /></td></tr>
</table>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// Print all HTML colors

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$textcolors = '<h1>HTML Text Colors</h1>';
$bgcolors = '<hr /><h1>HTML Background Colors</h1>';

foreach(TCPDF_COLORS::$webcolor as $k => $v) {
    $textcolors .= '<span color="#'.$v.'">'.$v.'</span> ';
    $bgcolors .= '<span bgcolor="#'.$v.'" color="#333333">'.$v.'</span> ';
}

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($textcolors, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->writeHTML($bgcolors, true, false, true, false, '');

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// Test word-wrap

// create some HTML content
$html = '<hr />
<h1>Various tests</h1>
<a href="#2">link to page 2</a><br />
<font face="courier"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> <font face="helvetica"><i>thisisanotherverylongword</i></font> <font face="times"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> thisisanotherverylongword <font face="times">thisisaverylongword</font> <font face="courier"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> <font face="helvetica"><i>thisisanotherverylongword</i></font> <font face="times"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> thisisanotherverylongword <font face="times">thisisaverylongword</font> <font face="courier"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> <font face="helvetica"><i>thisisanotherverylongword</i></font> <font face="times"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> thisisanotherverylongword <font face="times">thisisaverylongword</font> <font face="courier"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> <font face="helvetica"><i>thisisanotherverylongword</i></font> <font face="times"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> thisisanotherverylongword <font face="times">thisisaverylongword</font> <font face="courier"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> <font face="helvetica"><i>thisisanotherverylongword</i></font> <font face="times"><b>thisisaverylongword</b></font> thisisanotherverylongword <font face="times">thisisaverylongword</font>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// Test fonts nesting
$html1 = 'Default <font face="courier">Courier <font face="helvetica">Helvetica <font face="times">Times <font face="dejavusans">dejavusans </font>Times </font>Helvetica </font>Courier </font>Default';
$html2 = '<small>small text</small> normal <small>small text</small> normal <sub>subscript</sub> normal <sup>superscript</sup> normal';
$html3 = '<font size="10" color="#ff7f50">The</font> <font size="10" color="#6495ed">quick</font> <font size="14" color="#dc143c">brown</font> <font size="18" color="#008000">fox</font> <font size="22"><a href="http://www.tcpdf.org">jumps</a></font> <font size="22" color="#a0522d">over</font> <font size="18" color="#da70d6">the</font> <font size="14" color="#9400d3">lazy</font> <font size="10" color="#4169el">dog</font>.';

$html = $html1.'<br />'.$html2.'<br />'.$html3.'<br />'.$html3.'<br />'.$html2;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// test pre tag

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOF
<div style="background-color:#880000;color:white;">
Hello World!<br />
Hello
</div>
<pre style="background-color:#336699;color:white;">
int main() {
    printf("HelloWorld");
    return 0;
}
</pre>
<tt>Monospace font</tt>, normal font, <tt>monospace font</tt>, normal font.
<br />
<div style="background-color:#880000;color:white;">DIV LEVEL 1<div style="background-color:#008800;color:white;">DIV LEVEL 2</div>DIV LEVEL 1</div>
<br />
<span style="background-color:#880000;color:white;">SPAN LEVEL 1 <span style="background-color:#008800;color:white;">SPAN LEVEL 2</span> SPAN LEVEL 1</span>
EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// test custom bullet points for list

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOF
<h1>Test custom bullet image for list items</h1>
<ul style="font-size:14pt;list-style-type:img|png|4|4|images/logo_example.png">
    <li>test custom bullet image</li>
    <li>test custom bullet image</li>
    <li>test custom bullet image</li>
    <li>test custom bullet image</li>
<ul>
EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

A more specific and simplified example including retrieving the HTML from a file.

Not tested, but use as a concept;

```
<?php

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// create some HTML content
$html = file_get_contents('path/to/file/with.html');

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: That's why I mentioned it's a pre designed page and I've to print it directly. I guess TCPDF doesn't do this.

Comment: Retrieve the contents of your HTML in a string (for example with `file_get_contents`), and let TCPDF do the rest. As far as I know TCPDF is one of the only options for HTML to PDF's (using PHP).

Comment: In the code you wrote above, we have to write  in the $html ... But I need something like just entering the .html file name in the code and it saves as pdf

Comment: Added a simplified example to my answer.

Comment: This code won't work even bro. I'm using php to post data. I've made a resume creator which collects all inputs and post it and then resume is displayed in a php page

Comment: Then you would have to rebuild the page in PHP and HTML, or save a copy of the results page locally, or parse it with a buffer with the `ob_*` functions. All in all, it's really not easy. Styling is a nightmare with PDF conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution for this, and here are the project criteria:

1. Windows OS
2. Document must be rendered in HTML first
3. HTML must be saved as .PDF
4. PDF must be sent to printer

In order to implement the same solution, you will need to have Google Chrome installed, and the path (typically C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application) should be in your environment variables, or else you will need the full path when calling chrome.exe:

```
//HTML content
$html = 'Your html here'; //Make sure to include references to any style sheets

//Name of HTML file
$htmlFileName = 'test.html';

//Name of PDF file
$pdfFileName = 'test.pdf';

//Command that will be executed using exec()
$savePDFCMD = "chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>/$pdfFileName ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>/$htmlFileName";

//Kill command for Chrome process
$endChromeCMD = 'taskkill /IM chrome.exe';

//Create HTML file at project root
file_put_contents($htmlFileName, $html);

//Convert HTML to PDF using Headless Google Chrome (there will be header and footer info such as timestamps and file location - This can be removed with CSS).
exec($savePDFCMD);

//Ends chrome.exe process
exec($endChromeCMD);

//You will need to know the printer's IP address and the port it receives files on (ask your IT manager)
$fp = pfsocketopen("<PRINTER_IP_ADDRESS>", Port);

//Sends PDF to the print que
fputs($fp, file_get_contents($pdfFileName));

//Close connection after file has been printed
fclose($fp);

//Deletes temp files used for printing
unlink($htmlFileName);
unlink($pdfFileName);
```